# Draw shapes using C language without graphics library

Tags: c

I have to make console program which will draw circle, line, parabola 
I made it using graphics library but my teacher asked me to make it without any library.

I have tried a lot  without any result, I don't know how to draw it without graphics library

This is my code:

```
#include<graphics.h>

draw_line(int a,int b){
    int y;int x=3;
    for(x=-2;x<=2;x++)
    {
        y=a*x+b;
        moveto(x,y);

        printf("*");
    }
}

draw_circle(a,b,r){
    float newx;float newy;
    float angle;
    for(angle=0;angle<=360;angle+=0.1)
    {
        newx=a+cos(radians)*r;
        newy=b+sin(radians)*r;

        moveto(newx,newy);
        printf("*");
    }
}
draw_parabola(int a,int b,int c)
{

    float x; float y;
    for(x=0.0;x<=2.0;x+=0.1){

       y = (float) pow((float) a*x,2)+(float) pow((float) b*x,2)+c;
       printf("%f",y);printf("\n");
       printf("%f",x);printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: _"my teacher asked me to make it without any library"_ Good luck on that

Comment: I removed the c++ tag for you because c++ and c guys will flame you more than your local fast food joint does its burgers (and you seem to be using c)

Comment: 1. Please format your program correctly, especially the useless empty lines. 2. You're writing in pre-ANSI C which has been obsolete for the last 20 years.

Comment: ok thank you very much I am so sorry about this mistake

Comment: Why is your teacher forcing you to use Turbo C in the year 2017? It means they are very much incompetent. And apparently teaching bad habits, to make you a bad programmer. You need to find a better source of learning.

Comment: `moveto()` IS A LIBRARY function. I will surprised, if `moveto()` be compatible with `printf()`

Comment: I'd very much like to know how to do graphics without using a graphics library.

Comment: _my teacher asked me to make it without any library_, IMO you either misunderstood your teacher or your translation into english is wrong.

Comment: Fill `screen[width][height]` 2D array with dots or spaces and then print it to console.

Comment: I know that but our teacher like the old system teaching so I talked to him about this point without result every time he say " you must to do every thing s without using any library if you want to be good programmer "

Comment: The only alternative to using a graphics library is to poke bytes directly into the video-buffer memory...which used to be exposed on VGA  graphics adapters, but is likely not on modern graphics hardware.  See http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vgamem.htm I used to do this to draw graphics from QBASIC via the 0xA0000 base address.

Comment: @M.Bwe well, extract the code you use from the graphics library and put it into a source file of your own, then state that you are not using a library:)   C does not have any graphics functionality, so your exercise is literally impossible unless you are umm. 'economical with the truth':)

Comment: @M.Bwe - What exactly does “I tried without any result” mean?  What output are you expecting, and what output are you actually getting?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: I tried a lot without result because I searched into internet and there are no body know hoe to do

Comment: @M.Bwe: the sentiment behind your teacher's statement is correct (you need to understand the underlying workings to make expert use of a library or higher-lever API) but don't misconstrue that advice to mean that you shouldn't use libraries in general.  His proscription on library code is only valid for learning exercises.

Comment: That link I posted is valid circa the same time Turbo C++ 3.0 was available for sale.  I'll be stunned if `graphics.h` isn't implemented via direct manipulation of the VGA video buffer.

Comment: Presenting the mirror of [x2ftp.oulu.fi](ftp://ftp.lanet.lv/pub/programming/mirror-x2ftp/)

Comment: I remember there was a good GFX tutorial there, though it was for Turbo Pascal, but adaptable... EDIT: found, see the [Asphyxia tutorials](ftp://ftp.lanet.lv/pub/programming/mirror-x2ftp/docs/) here named `tutNNnew.zip` for some oldskool goodness.

Comment: "you must to do every thing s without using any library if you want to be good programmer" That's simply stupid. Being a good programmer means that you **must be able** to do it without library. But it doesn't mean that you do it every time. Spending tons of hours while there is a library waiting for you is a waste of money. A good programmer knows when to use an existing solution. Given that the license fits your needs. BTW: Are you allowed to use standard C library? ;)

Answer (score 4):

A console program can draw a circle like this:

```
  ***
*     *
*     *
  ***
```

A parabola like this:

```
*         *
*         *
*         *
 *       *
 *       *
  *     *
    ***
```

etc.

And you do not need a graphics library for that.

Is that what you want ?

--EDIT--

Example that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int eq_circle(int x, int y, int radius)
{
        return x*x+y*y - radius;
}

int eq_parabol(int x, int y)
{
        return x*x-y;
}

void draw_circle(int radius)
{
        int x, y;
        for (x=-5; x<=5; x++) {
                for (y=-10; y<=10; y++) {
                        if (eq_circle(x, y, radius) < 0) printf("  ");
                        else printf("**");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}

void draw_parabol()
{
        int x, y;
        for (x=-5; x<=5; x++) {
                for (y=-10; y<=10; y++) {
                        if (eq_parabol(x, y) < 0) printf(" ");
                        else printf("*");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
        draw_circle(8);
        printf("\n");
        draw_parabol();
}
```

Result:

```
******************************************
******************************************
******************************************
******************      ******************
****************          ****************
****************          ****************
****************          ****************
******************      ******************
******************************************
******************************************
******************************************

*********************
*********************
******************** 
***************      
************         
***********          
************         
***************      
******************** 
*********************
*********************
```

Comment: yes that what I need

Comment: user can determine the radius of the circle and coefficients a, b because the circle formula is (x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2=r^2

Answer (score 4):

> my teacher asked me to make it without any library.

You could do [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751972/841108).

Otherwise, study the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). You'll see that graphics is not standardized in C. So you then have to write some implementation specific code.

On current desktop and laptop operating systems (Linux, Windows, MacOSX, ...) and computers, the graphics hardware is very complex and accessible thru several complex layers of software. It is not reasonable to avoid all of them. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410189/50557).

You could ask your teacher if you are allowed to use some portable library like [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [libcairo](https://cairographics.org/).... or you could feed some existing graphical program (e.g. [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/), [`dot`](https://www.graphviz.org/), ....) with data.

BTW, your code should declare all your routines as giving `void`, e.g. 
 `void draw_line(int a,int b);` etc...